# Preventing shell mode from treating ! as a history reference

Tags: shell-mode, gdb, history, ftp

Various command-line tools, such as gdb, ftp, sftp, etc, use ! to prefix a command to be run in a shell. So (for instance) `!mkdir foo` will make a directory called foo. When using these tools inside emacs shell-mode, the shell-mode treats the ! as a history reference, does a history lookup, and expands the result before putting the command in the history ring. So if I have previously typed `mkdir bar`, shell-mode puts `mkdir bar foo` into the history ring.

Can I easily suppress all special treatment of ! in the shell history? I want the history to contain `!mkdir foo`. I don't ever use ! at the shell, so I'd be happy with a way of turning this off entirely, although I suppose it could be made switchable based on the prompt.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out: `(setq shell-input-autoexpand nil)`. I spent a long while looking at `comint-input-autoexpand` which was getting mysteriously set to `'history`: this is done by shell-mode based on `shell-input-autoexpand`. I don't see an easy way to make it prompt-dependent, though.